# How to globally order multiple ordered observables in Monix

Tags: scala, reactive-programming, monifu, monix

Suppose I have multiple iterators that are ordered. If I wanted to merge these iterators while globally ordering them (e.g. `[(1,3,4), (2,4,5)] -> [1,2,3,4,4,5]`) using [monix](https://github.com/monixio/monix) how would I do it?

Comment: I don't know Monix; are these just standard Scala iterators?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul: Yes, just standard Scala iterators.

Comment: Right. Answer coming.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't use Monix, but I'm not sure if that's relevant

```
import scala.collection.BufferedIterator


def merge[A:Ordering](xs: Seq[Iterator[A]]) = 
  new Iterator[A] {
    val its = xs.map(_.buffered)
    def hasNext = its.exists(_.hasNext)
    def next = its.filter{ _.hasNext}
                  .minBy(_.head)
                  .next
  }


val ys = merge(Seq(List(1,3,5).toIterator, List(2,4,6).toIterator, List(10,11).toIterator))

ys.toList  //> res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11)
```

Comment: Thanks, I did wanted to know how it can be done using Monix (or one of those reactive programming libraries), but it's still useful.

Comment: Nicely done.  Since `ord` is unused couldn't you have declared `merge[A:Ordering]`?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have time to look into Monix, but I'm not sure how merging iterators and that are connected. Can you expand, maybe in your question?

Comment: @jwh, yes. I forgot about that. Edited. Also, the tuple stuff was pointless with a bit more thought, so simplified things

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul: I guess I should have said `Observable` instead of iterators (though they are the same as in they both represent a stream). I wanted to use Monix because in theory it allows you to tune how it gets executed unlike the std library. For example, imagine each iterator's `next` method involving some fair amount of calculation. Monix should allow this to be done in multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks. That's why I asked if they were standard iterators before answering :) to understand what you were working with.  If I get time I'll take a look at Monix Observables.

Answer (score 0):

Since observable is a stream of items, it can be generalized as two types:

- Finite streams
- Infinite streams

Note that, in order to sort correctly, you'll need all the items. So, there's no easy way to do this.

*For finite streams*, you'll have to accumulate all the items and then sort. You can turn this back into an observable with `Observable.fromIterable`.

```
val items = List((1,3,4), (2,4,5))

val sortedList = Observable
  .fromIterable(items)
  .flatMap(item => Observable.fromIterable(List(item._1, item._2, item._3)))
  .toListL // Flatten to an Observable[Int]
  .map(_.sorted)
```

For infinite streams, the only thing you can do is to buffer the items up to a certain time or size. I don't see any way around since you don't know when the stream will end.

For example,

```
val itemsStream: Observable[(Int, Int, Int)] = ???

itemsStream
  .bufferIntrospective(10)
  .flatMap((itemList: List[(Int, Int, Int)]) => // You'll have to sort this
     ???
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I needed merge-sorting monix observables, and couldn't find a solution, this is how I solved it.

The idea is to use `bufferWhile` on the two `head`s of the lists, so that you can hold the actual values at hand, and check which of them is smaller

```scala
  private def mergeSortInternal(aHead: Observable[Int], bHead: Observable[Int], aTail: Observable[Int], bTail: Observable[Int]): Observable[Int] = {
    (aHead.isEmpty ++ bHead.isEmpty).bufferWhile(_ => true).map {
      isEmptyPair: Seq[Boolean] =>
        val Seq(aIsEmpty, bIsEmpty) = isEmptyPair
        if (aIsEmpty) {
          bHead ++ bTail
        }
        else if (bIsEmpty) {
          aHead ++ aTail
        }
        else {
          {
            (aHead ++ bHead).bufferWhile(_ => true).map((heads: Seq[Int]) => {
              val Seq(aHeadValue, bHeadValue) = heads
              if (aHeadValue < bHeadValue) {
                Observable(aHeadValue) ++ mergeSortInternal(aTail.head, bHead, aTail.tail, bTail)
              }
              else {
                Observable(bHeadValue) ++ mergeSortInternal(aHead, bTail.head, aTail, bTail.tail)
              }
            }).flatten
          }

        }
    }.flatten
  }
  
  private def mergeSort(a: Observable[Int], b: Observable[Int]) = {
    mergeSortInternal(a.head, b.head, a.tail, b.tail)
  }
```